# Shell command xargs & sed doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, sed, xargs

I just want to batch modify the suffix of the files,but it doesn't work!
The command line I used as below:

```
ls *html | xargs  -I{}  echo "\`echo {} |  sed 's/html/css/g'\`"
```

However, when I just used `ls *html`,it shows:

```
file1.html  file2.html  file3.html  file4.html  file5.html
```

used `ls *html | sed 's/html/css/g'`,it shows as I expected!
like this:

```
file1.css file2.css file3.css file4.css file5.css
```

I work on Mac OS. Could anyone give me some suggestions? 
Thans in advance.

Comment: Where do you actually rename/move the files on disk?

Answer (score 4):

Because the backquotes are in double quotes, it gets executed immediately by the shell and not by xargs on each file.

The result is the same as

```
ls *html | xargs -I{} echo "{}"
```

However, if you use single quotes, you run into other troubles. You end up having to do something like this:

```
ls *html | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo `echo {} | sed '\''s/html/css/g'\''`'
```

but it gets to be a mess, and we haven't even got to the actual renaming yet.

Using a loop is a bit nicer:

```
for file in *html; do
  newname=${file%html}css
  mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: To avoid the unneeded pipeline and to work properly even if `file` contains the character string `html` more than once, consider replacing `newname=\`echo "$file" | sed 's/html/css/g'\`` with `newname=${file%html}css`.

Comment: Thank you very very much.I got it.and the same thanks to @John1024

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
ls *html | parallel echo before {} after {.}.css
```